# How can I develop Kooboo modules with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, kooboo

Kooboo 4.3 and up comes with a VSI file containing a project template for a Kooboo module. This project template can only be installed to Visual Studio 2010 and 2012 but not to 2013.

How can I get this project template in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: If you are using Kooboo, can you add your support please to the Area 51 proposal for a dedicated Kooboo Stack Exchange sub site: area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79383/kooboo

Comment: @MarkSizer I already did a few weeks ago. I am follower #8.

Comment: Sorry, you have a different Avatar on there, I didn't realise you'd already added.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @MarkSizer For some reason Area51 only supports Gravatar and does not use the avatar I uploaded to SE. This is why I don't have this avatar over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to extract the KoobooModule.zip from the VSI file and then save it in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#\Web`. There are two ways to do this.

### Using 7-Zip

Open the VSI file with 7-Zip and navigate to `.rsrc\42\ZIPDATA\`. Don't worry if this does not look like a directory, simply double click it and 7-Zip will open it. Extract the `KoobooModule.zip` to the directory given above.

### Using Visual Studio 2010/2012

I have not tested this but from looking at tutorials on the web this is how it should work. Double click the VSI file. The Visual Studio content installer will pop up and allow you to install the file. `KoobooModule.zip` can now be found in your Visual Studio project templates folder. It looks like the path given above, just replace the 2013 with your version (2010 or 2012). Copy `KoobooModule.zip` to the 2013 directory.

Comment: These instructions are still relevant for Visual Studio 2015. Thank you @Chris!